# Best way to add an javascript-jquery-and-nacl page in drupal 7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7, google-nativeclient

I have an html page that calls some javascript and jQuery functions and also has an 'embed' tag to load a NaCl (native client) module. The page works fine as is but now I would like to build a web site that serves this page. I have set up a drupal 7 site but I am confused as to the best way to include my page.

I thought that I could just add a basic-page content, paste my code in the text editor and then make sure that the page can find all the necessary .js and nacl files. But this does not do the trick. (I have installed CKEditor and use full HTML option).

I have read posts advising to include javascript code in theme templates via .info. Or to add as a js library, or in a module. I am not sure which would be the best way to go. For now I just need to be able to write a drupal "basic page" node that calls my javascript and load my NaCl module. Ideally this should be theme independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found a simple way to add javascript and jquery in drupal 7 without building your own module, without including it in a theme and without incorporating your library yourself. There is a module that includes your javascript library for you and manages its inclusion in drupal 7. It makes your javascript available for each page: drupal.org/project/javascript_libraries –